# Create View of MYSQL to sqlite3

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have this two views in mysql and I when I execute they in sqlite3 throws me the error

```
Error: near "("
```

I have cheked it: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

**The Views:**

```
CREATE VIEW `municipios_extendido` AS (select `municipios`.`municipio` AS `municipio`,`provincias`.`provincia` AS `provincia`,`comunidades`.`comunidad` AS `comunidad`,`municipios`.`latitud` AS `latitud`,`municipios`.`longitud` AS `longitud` from ((`municipios` join `provincias` on((`provincias`.`id` = `municipios`.`provincia_id`))) join `comunidades` on((`provincias`.`comunidad_id` = `comunidades`.`id`))))


CREATE VIEW `municipio_posicion` AS select distinct `c`.`name` AS `municipio`,`m`.`provincia` AS `provincia`,`m`.`comunidad` AS `comunidad`,`m`.`latitud` AS `latitud`,`m`.`longitud` AS `longitud` from (`xhwpk_k2_categories` `c` join `municipios_extendido` `m`) where (`c`.`name` = `m`.`municipio`)
```

Comment: You have and extra `(` between `join 'comunidades' on(('provincias'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have from ((`municipios` join `provincias` on((`provincias   you get the picture

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean

Comment: you have extra '(' sprinkled around

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW `municipios_extendido` AS 
    SELECT `municipios`.`municipio` AS `municipio`,`provincias`.`provincia` AS `provincia`,`comunidades`.`comunidad` AS `comunidad`,`municipios`.`latitud` AS `latitud`,`municipios`.`longitud` AS `longitud` 
    FROM `municipios` 
    join `provincias` on  (`provincias`.`id` = `municipios`.`provincia_id`) 
    join `comunidades` on (`provincias`.`comunidad_id` = `comunidades`.`id`)


CREATE VIEW `municipio_posicion` AS 
    SELECT distinct `c`.`name` AS `municipio`,`m`.`provincia` AS `provincia`,`m`.`comunidad` AS `comunidad`,`m`.`latitud` AS `latitud`,`m`.`longitud` AS `longitud` 
    FROM `xhwpk_k2_categories` `c` 
    JOIN `municipios_extendido` `m` ADD_HERE_YOUR_ON_CLAUSE
    WHERE `c`.`name` = `m`.`municipio`
```